# Why are the parameters not working in my INSERT statement?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-ce, sql-insert

I am trying to insert some info to the DB using parameters but instead of adding parameter value the parameter name is added to DB.
here is my code:

```
 try {              
     vSqlCeConnection.Open();
      SqlCeCommand vCommand = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO  BusinessCards 
                               (  CalligraphyNeeded , Comments , NameEnglish 
                               , JobTitleEnglish , NameArabic , JobTitleArabic
                                ,BOBOX , HomePhoneNumber 
                               , FAXNumber , OfficePhoneNumber , MobileNumber , Email )
                         VALUES
                               (   @CalligraphyNeeded, '@Comments' ,'@NameEnglish' 
                                ,'@JobTitleEnglish' ,'@NameArabic' ,'@JobTitleArabic'
                                ,'@BOBOX' ,'@HomePhoneNumber' 
                               ,'@FAXNumber' ,'@OfficePhoneNumber' ,'@MobileNumber'
                                ,'@Email'  )  " , vSqlCeConnection);




            if (checkBoxCalligraphy.Checked == true)
            {
                vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalligraphyNeeded", 1);
            }
            else
            {
                vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalligraphyNeeded", 0);
            }
            vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", richTextBoxComments.Text );
            vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameEnglish", textBoxEnglishName.Text);                vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitleEnglish",richTextBoxEnglishJobTitle.Text);
            vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameArabic", textBoxArabicName.Text + " ff");
            vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitleArabic", richTextBoxArabicJobTiltle.Text + " ff");
            vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BOBOX", textBoxPOBox.Text + " ff");
            vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhoneNumber", textBoxHomePhone.Text + " ff");
            vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FAXNumber", textBoxFax.Text + " ff");
            vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficePhoneNumber", textBoxOfficePhone.Text + " ff");
            vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", textBoxMobile.Text + " ff");
            vCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBoxEmail.Text + " ff");
            MessageBox.Show(vCommand.CommandText);
            vCommand.Prepare();
                vCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry error: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

But when I execute the code it give me this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because the parameters are enlosed with single quotes causing it to be converted into *string literals*, remove the single quotes around them and it will surely work.

Parameters are identifiers and not string literals so they must not be wrap with single quotes.

```
VALUES
(   @CalligraphyNeeded, @Comments , @NameEnglish 
   ,@JobTitleEnglish , @NameArabic , @JobTitleArabic
   ,@BOBOX , @HomePhoneNumber 
   ,@FAXNumber , @OfficePhoneNumber , @MobileNumber
   ,@Email  
)
```

Comment: Thanks JW,
What an obvious mistake :(

Comment: Actually in OP's code, the first parameter (CalligraphyNeeded) was correct and even made it to the database as a proper value.